# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 15 Errors

Tags: php, smarty

I am receiving a number of `PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 15` error in my apache2 error log.

I beleive that the error relates to the below PHP code, does anyone have any suggestions on how to correct this? I have seen other suggestions to use isset?

`{if $GLOBAL.userdata.username|default:""|lower == $CONTRIBSHARES[shares].account|lower}{assign var=listed value=1}<tr class="success">{/if}
            {else}<tr>{/if}`

I'm using smarty template so the above code gets converted to:-

`<?php if (mb_strtolower((($tmp = @$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['GLOBAL']->value['userdata']['username'])===null||$tmp==='' ? '' : $tmp), 'UTF-8')==mb_strtolower($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['CONTRIBSHARES']->value[$_smarty_tpl->getVariable('smarty')->value['section']['shares']['index']]['account'], 'UTF-8')) {?><?php $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['listed'] = new Smarty_variable(1, null, 0);?><tr class="success"><?php }?>
            <?php } else { ?><tr><?php }?>`

Any suggestions on how to construct would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['CONTRIBSHARES']->value[$_smarty_tpl->getVariable('smarty')->value['section']['shares']['index']]['account']` Is one hell of a variable :s

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions to contruct this?